# Unit test for if() return; in a function

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

html:

```
<button [disabled]="isFormValid()"></button>
```

.ts:

```
isFormValid() {
    if (this.data.dataForm.valid && this.flag) {
      if (!!this.testData.data) {
       return !this.testData.data.dataForm.valid;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    } else {
      return !this.data.dataForm.valid;
    }
  }
```

I had a method like this with nested if conditions and multiple return statements. I'm learning unit testing and what could be the best approach to handle this method with multiple unit test cases.

Answer (score 0):

I find it most useful to treat the component template and typescript class as one unit to test. This way I am free refactor and move things without breaking tests and getting false positives in test results.

In your case to test it I would introduce a function that would return a handle to the button you want to test, as in:

```
function submitButton() {
    return fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.some-class')).nativeElement
}
```

This way I could create multiple test cases where I pass values to other form fields, call `submitButton.click()` and verify, that the action has / has not been done.

When setting form values (simulating user input) remember, that you may need to publish the `input` browser events so that angular updates the form.

Comment: How about spy on isFormValid() method and verify the if conditions ??